# Delay creating python dict until set/update

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, lazy-initialization

I have a Python dict-of-dict structure with a large number of outer-dict keys (millions to billions). The inner dicts are mostly empty, but can store key-value pairs. Currently I create a separate dict as each of the inner dicts. But it uses a lot of memory that I don't end up using. Each empty dict is small, but I have a lot of them. I'd like to delay creating the inner dict until needed.

Ideally, I'd like to even delay creating the inner dict until a key-value pair is **set** in the inner dict. I envision using a single DelayDict object for ALL outer-dict values. This object would act like an empty dict for get and **getitem** calls, but as soon as a **setitem** or update call comes in it would create an empty dict to take its place. I run into trouble having the delaydict object know how to connect the new empty dict with the dict-of-dict structure.

```
class DelayDict(object):    % can do much more - only showing get/set
    def __init__(self, dod):
        self.dictofdict = dod     % the outer dict
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        raise KeyError(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        replacement = {key: value}
        % replace myself in the outer dict!!
        self.dict-of-dict[?????] = replacement
```

I can't think of how to store the new replacement dict in the dict-of-dict structure so that it replaces the DelayDict class as the inner dict. I know properties can do similar things, but I believe the same fundamental trouble arises when I try to replace myself inside the outer dict.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what `collections.defaultdict(dict)` would do, isn't it? You could subclass it and override the `__missing__` method if you need to change the behaviour.

Comment: `defaultdict(dict)` only delays creating the inner dict until the outer key is created. I want to add outer keys without having to create the inner dict.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish outer keys with no inner keys from outer keys that aren't present at all?

Comment: I don't need to distinguish outer keys between with or without inner keys. Right now I build an inner dict for both types and one type sits empty. I want to eliminate all those empty dicts by using a single delaydict instead of all the empty inner dicts. The hard part is figuring out how to make the delaydict replace itself in the outer dict's "value" with a real dict when needed. It seems I need to store which outer key is used to get the inner dict.

Comment: You can't have a single inner object placeholder, because it needs to have a reference to both the outer object *and* the relevant key, otherwise a retained reference to it won't have the correct behaviour. Therefore you end up creating an instance for each missing value, and won't be saving anything over creating a dictionary for each missing value.

Comment: What about wrapping the whole interface in a class which takes a 2-tuple argument for getting and setting the inner dict. That way the relevant key would be supplied at call time rather than stored. To get to the inner dict, you have to supply the outer key -- there ought to be a way to use that information -- even if it isn't stored somewhere -- it is certainly in the code just 2 characters ahead of the inner key.  Seems like there should be a way...

Comment: @jonrsharpe (answer to an old comment) If you create (and destroy) the placeholders on demand, you won't need dozens of placeholders. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but I came across a similar problem. I'm not sure that it's a
good idea to try to spare some memory, but if you really need to do that, you should try to build your own data structure.

If you are stuck with the dict of dict, here's a solution.

First, you need a way to create keys in the `OuterDict` without value (value is `{}`) by default). if `OuterDict` is a wrapper around a dict `__d`:

```
def create(self, key):
    self.__d[key] = None
```

How much memory will you spare?

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = {}
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
136
```

As you pointed out, `None` is created only once, but you have to keep a reference on it. In Cpython (64 bits), it's 8 bytes. For 1 billion elements, you spare (136-8)* 10**9 bytes = 128 Gb (and not Mb, thanks!). You need to give a
placeholder when someone ask for the value. The placeholder keeps track of the outer dict and the key in the outer dict. It wraps a dict and assigns this dict to `outer[key]` when you assign a value.

No more talking, code:

```
class OuterDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__d = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        v = self.__d[key]
        if v is None: # an orphan key
            v = PlaceHolder(self.__d, key)
        return v

    def create(self, key):
        self.__d[key] = None

class PlaceHolder():
    def __init__(self, parent, key):
        self.__parent = parent
        self.__key = key
        self.__d = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__d[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not self.__d:
            self.__parent[self.__key] = self.__d  # copy me in the outer dict
        self.__d[key] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr("PlaceHolder for "+str(self.__d))

    # __len__, ...
```

A test:

```
o = OuterDict()
o.create("a") # a is empty
print (o["a"])

try:
    o["a"]["b"] # Key Error
except KeyError as e:
    print ("KeyError", e)

o["a"]["b"] = 2
print (o["a"])

# output:
# 'PlaceHolder for {}'
# KeyError 'b'
# {'b': 2}
```

Why it doesn't use much memory? Because you are not building billions of placeholders. You release them when you don't need them anymore. Maybe you will need just one at a time.

Possible improvements: you can create a pool of `PlaceHolders`. A stack may be a good data structure: recently created placeholder are likely to be released soon. When you need a new `PlaceHolder`, you
look into the stack, and if a placeholder has only one ref (`sys.getrefcount(ph) == 1`), you can use it. To fasten the process, when you are looking for
a free placeholder, you can remember the placeholder with the maximum refcount. You switch the free placeholder with this "max refcount" placeholder. Hence, the placeholders with the maximum
refcount are sent to the bottom of the stack.

Comment: I think your MB should be GB in the estimate of memory savings. Also, the dict doesn't create a None object for each entry -- it simply points to the single unique object called None. So... This looks like a great help. I'll try it out!  Thanks

Comment: @dschult You're right about MB/GB! I didn't realize my answer was so good... Will edit it.